# Sending connection metadata between two Net servers

Tags: node.js

Given the sample script below I am piping a TCP connection from one server to another which works just fine.

```
net = require "net"
log = console.log

# This server needs to receive custom data eg. (remoteAddress or an uuid)
target = net.createServer (socket) ->
  log('Target connection from ' + socket.remoteAddress)
target.listen(10000, '0.0.0.0', () -> log('Target ready'))

# User-facing server that pipes to the target server
front = net.createServer (socket) ->
  log('Front connection from ' + socket.remoteAddress)
  socket.on 'data', (data) ->
    socket.proxy = net.createConnection 10000, () ->
      socket.proxy.write(data)
      socket.pipe(socket.proxy).pipe(socket)

front.listen(8006, '0.0.0.0', () -> log('Front ready'))
```

The problem I am facing is that I need to pass the IP address (eg. `socket.remoteAddress`) of the original socket over to the other server.
It does not need to override target's `socket.remoteAddress`, just retrieve the original IP one way or another.

Here is how I am testing this:

```
$ telnet 172.0.0.50 8006
Trying 172.0.0.50...
Connected to 172.0.0.50.
Escape character is '^]'.
SendingData
```

which results in:

```
Target ready
Front ready
Front connection from 172.0.0.1
Target connection from 127.0.0.1
```

Note that the `target` server receives the IP address of the `front` server, and I completely understand why.

I cannot use the `data` unfortunately as it might be completely encrypted by client.

Comment: x-forwarder-for is a HTTP header and has nothing to do with TCP streams unfortunately. The stream might be encrypted in which case I cannot inspect whether it is HTTP, TLS or something else.

Comment: You don't need to care whether the data is encrypted or not. You could just prepend the data with uint32 formated ip. And when backend recieve the proxied data, remove the prepended ip and parse it.

Comment: This is actually interesting idea. Not the cleanest one but definitely worth giving a go. Thanks Jerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking more about a solution that does not need to twiddle about data there is one important fact that both servers know about the socket port that opened the connection to target. Which is `socket.localPort` of front connection socket and `socket.remotePort` of the target server's socket.

This fact make it possible to build a port/ip map:

```
net = require "net"
log = console.log

portMap = {}

# This server needs to receive custom data eg. (remoteAddress or an uuid)
target = net.createServer (socket) ->
  socket.once 'data', (data) ->
    socket.id = portMap[socket.remotePort]
    log('Target connection from ' + socket.id);

target.listen(10000, '0.0.0.0', () -> log('Target ready'))

# User-facing server that pipes to the target server
front = net.createServer (socket) ->
  log('Front connection from ' + socket.remoteAddress)
  socket.once 'data', (data) ->
    socket.proxy = net.createConnection 10000, () ->
      portMap[socket.proxy.localPort] = socket.remoteAddress;
      socket.proxy.write(data)
      socket.pipe(socket.proxy).pipe(socket)

front.listen(8006, '0.0.0.0', () -> log('Front ready'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another cleaner approach could be that you can send the actual `remoteAddress` during the socket.proxy connection and then remembering it at the target server. This way, you won't have to add overhead to the data.

Also in your original code, you are making a new socket connection to target server on every 'data' event. I don't think it's intentional but this way, you will soon hit the open file limit if the traffic is high.

So I would suggest that you make a socket connection to target server only once when you have got a new socket connection to the front server. After that, your code should look like this:

```
var net = require("net");
const log = console.log;

target = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  log('Target connection from ' + socket.remoteAddress);
  socket.once('data', function(data){
    socket.id = data.toString(); // Now, use socket.id whenever you want at the target server.
  });
});

target.listen(10000, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  log('Target ready');
});

var front = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  log('Front connection from ' + socket.remoteAddress);
  socket.proxy = net.createConnection(10000, function() {
    socket.proxy.write(socket.remoteAddress);
  });
  socket.pipe(socket.proxy).pipe(socket);
});

front.listen(8006, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  log('Front ready');
});
```

For checking the number of connections to your server, you can use [server.getConnections](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_getconnections_callback). This way, you can keep things from going out of the bound.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am testing this approach now. "Also in your original code, you are making a new socket connection to target server on every 'data' event. I don't think it's intentional" It actually is, since I have multiple target servers from which I can pick up only upon receiving first bytes on the front server.

Comment: But then there might be some cases where your encrypted data might get corrupted if the data/request received at the front server came in multiple chunks and each chunk went to a different target server. You might have already handled this situation. I am just thinking out loud :)

Comment: I think the ip sent to the backend server should be length-fixed, and backend assume the first n-byte data is the ip address. Because tcp is a stream protocal. When front-end write two packet to the backend, The backend may recieve them in the original format, or all joined together, thus mass up the program.

Comment: I think I'll accept the answer as proposed by @Punit Mittal as it does actually work. Yet need to figure out how to extract the IP address from the payload when the targets server is a http/https express.js server.